# How to include a JSON column property in Laravel API Resource

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model which is illustrated below which I am struggling to access a very trivial property.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


class Vendor extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, SoftDeletes;

    protected $guard = 'vendor';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'slug','images'
    ];
 
    //images is a json column


    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
    ];


}
```

Within my model I now have a property which is

```
 public function coverImage()
    {
        return \Storage::disk('s3')->url( $this->images['cover']);
    }
```

I am basically trying to retrieve a property within my JSON column but whenever I try to access it in my API resource, it throws the error:

```
ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in file C:\...\Models\Vendor.php on line 63
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Not really a solution for your problem, but it would probably be easier to manage if you have the images as a model with a one to many relation with the vendor. That way you can easily get all your related models. You can also have a look at the [spatie/media-library](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) package

Answer (score 0):

I had a lightbulb moment, all I needed to do was to expose it in my VendorResource as thus

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class VendorResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'coverImage'=> \Storage::disk('s3')->url( $this->images['cover'])
            ];
    }
}
```